# How to shuffle or randomize a linked list

Tags: c#, random, linked-list

i'm trying to shuffle or randomize a LinkedList of images in this case but the way i've set it up it seems to go on indefinetely

the shuffling is fairly simple, you have the list, note the last entry, then take the first entry and put it at a random spot in the list, and then the next first entry, etc. until the top entry is the entry you noted as the last, you put that entry in a random place in the list and the list is shuffled.

here's my code:

```
class ShuffleClass
{
    private LinkedList<Image> library;
    private Image lastCard;
    private Image topCard;
    private Random rng;
    private int place;
    private LinkedListNode<Image> node;

    public LinkedList<Image> shuffle(LinkedList<Image> library)
    {
        this.library = library;
        lastCard = library.Last.Value;
        rng = new Random();

        while (library.First.Value != lastCard)
        {
            topCard = library.First.Value;
            library.RemoveFirst();
            place = rng.Next(1,library.Count+1);

            if (place == library.Count)
            {
                library.AddBefore(library.Last, topCard);
            }
            else
            { 
                node = library.Find(library.ElementAt(place));
                library.AddBefore(node, topCard);
            }

        }
        topCard = library.First.Value;
        library.RemoveFirst();
        place = rng.Next(0,library.Count+1);
        if(place == library.Count)
        {
            library.AddBefore(library.Last, topCard);
        }
        else
        {
            node = library.Find(library.ElementAt(place));
            library.AddBefore(node, topCard);
        }
        return library;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your problem? Does your code just not work?

Comment: it keeps running the loop endlessly

Comment: The problem with your code is that your end-condition will never be reached because you keep the last element at the last position...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Random Class to shuffle your list:

```
public static void Shuffle()
{
    Random Rand = new Random();
    LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 });

    foreach (int i in list)
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);

    Console.WriteLine();
    int size = list.Count;

    //Shuffle the list
    list =  new LinkedList<int>(list.OrderBy((o) =>
    {
        return (Rand.Next() % size);
    }));

    foreach (int i in list)
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output may be something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
10 2 17 7 9 15 8 14 1 12 13 16 4 18 3 5 11 20 19 6
```

Comment: return (Rand.Next() % size) - 1; can be changed to return (Rand.Next());

Comment: Actually, given the implementation, the range of the random number is irrelevant, as it's not ever used directly as an index into the original collection. By the same token, you're more likely to get a well-distributed shuffle if you _don't_ try to limit the range of the random number, because a duplicated random number (more likely with the smaller range) introduces side-effects from the sort into the random ordering.

Comment: Not to mention that `OrderBy()` is going to evaluate the key selector multiple times for what it thinks is the same element, but getting different values for the same element may break the sort.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The question, does breaking the sort make it more or less random? Something to ponder :) Of course, it may just throw an exception.

Comment: @Lasse: indeed, different sort algorithms will respond differently. The real problem is that the outcome is uncertain and undocumented. Even if no exception is thrown, one may not wind up with a uniform distribution in the randomness. Not necessarily "more" or "less" random, but just "different" random where uniform was expected. I would certainly discourage approaching shuffling this way, as a general rule.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Oh, without a doubt, it was just something to ponder :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue with the code you have is that, as you've found, it doesn't terminate. You only ever call `AddBefore()`, which has no way to add an element *after* the last element of the linked list, and so the last element of the linked list can't possibly change, never mind have its value moved to the beginning of the list.

Even if you fixed that problem, the loop still wouldn't be right, because there's no reason to expect that the last value in the list would get moved to the first only if you had finished shuffling the list.

If you really want to shuffle the list in-place, you still need to start with a shuffle algorithm that is basically correct, i.e. Fisher-Yates, but where the swap function knows how to swap elements in the linked list instead of just swapping array elements (as in the usual implementation of Fisher-Yates).

Note, however, that doing it that way is fairly expensive, especially as the list gets large, because you wind up having to scan through the list so many times (twice for each swap).

You can cut that cost in half if you instead shuffle an array of indexes into the list, and then build a new list from that. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<int> test = new LinkedList<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10)),
            shuffled = Shuffle(test);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", shuffled));
    }

    static LinkedList<T> Shuffle<T>(LinkedList<T> source)
    {
        LinkedList<T> result = new LinkedList<T>();
        int[] choices = Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count).ToArray();

        ShuffleArray(choices);
        foreach (int choice in choices)
        {
            result.AddLast(ElementAt(source, choice));
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void ShuffleArray<T>(T[] array)
    {
        // Naturally, in real code you'd want to reuse the same Random object
        // across multiple calls, by making it static readonly
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i);

            if (i - 1 != j)
            {
                T t = array[i - 1];

                array[i - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    static T ElementAt<T>(LinkedList<T> source, int index)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> current = source.First;

        while (index-- > 0)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }

        return current.Value;
    }
}
```

If you really do want and/or need to shuffle the list in-place, then you could do something more like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<int> test = new LinkedList<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));

        ShuffleLinkedList(test);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", test));
    }

    static void ShuffleLinkedList<T>(LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        // Naturally, in real code you'd want to reuse the same Random object
        // across multiple calls, by making it static readonly
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = list.Count; i > 1; i--)
        {
            SwapNodes(list, i - 1, random.Next(i));
        }
    }

    static void SwapNodes<T>(LinkedList<T> list, int i, int j)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            LinkedListNode<T> node1 = NodeAt(list, i), node2 = NodeAt(list, j),
                nodeBefore1 = node1.Previous, nodeBefore2 = node2.Previous;

            if (nodeBefore1 == node2)
            {
                list.Remove(node1);
                AddAfter(list, nodeBefore2, node1);
            }
            else if (nodeBefore2 == node1)
            {
                list.Remove(node2);
                AddAfter(list, nodeBefore1, node2);
            }
            else
            {
                list.Remove(node1);
                list.Remove(node2);
                AddAfter(list, nodeBefore2, node1);
                AddAfter(list, nodeBefore1, node2);
            }
        }
    }

    static void AddAfter<T>(LinkedList<T> list, LinkedListNode<T> after, LinkedListNode<T> add)
    {
        if (after != null)
        {
            list.AddAfter(after, add);
        }
        else
        {
            list.AddFirst(add);
        }
    }

    static LinkedListNode<T> NodeAt<T>(LinkedList<T> source, int index)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> current = source.First;

        while (index-- > 0)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }

        return current;
    }
}
```

Note how in both of these examples, the logic is broken down into much smaller methods. It can be very hard to achieve correct results when you try to put everything into a single method, and even harder to debug incorrect results when you've done so, because it's hard to examine and verify each smaller bit of logic in your code in isolation.

The in-place approach can be improved upon though, by taking advantage of the linked-list nature of the data structure. I.e. while an array benefits by being shuffled through swapping, so that we don't have to otherwise shift elements around in the array, we can shuffle a list by selecting a random element, removing it, and moving it to the end. As long as we make sure we select from a shorter and shorter subset of the list, we'll get a uniformly distributed shuffle.

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<int> test = new LinkedList<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));

        ShuffleLinkedList(test);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", test));
    }

    static void ShuffleLinkedList<T>(LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        // Naturally, in real code you'd want to reuse the same Random object
        // across multiple calls, by making it static readonly
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = list.Count; i > 1; i--)
        {
            LinkedListNode<T> node = NodeAt(list, random.Next(i));

            if (list.Last != node)
            {
                list.Remove(node);
                list.AddLast(node);
            }
        }
    }

    static LinkedListNode<T> NodeAt<T>(LinkedList<T> source, int index)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> current = source.First;

        while (index-- > 0)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }

        return current;
    }
}
```

No messy node swapping needed.

Finally, the most *efficient* time-wise (O(n) instead of O(n^2)), at the cost of some additional intermediate memory consumption, is to simply copy all of the elements from the list to an array, shuffle that, and add them back to the original list:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<int> test = new LinkedList<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));

        Shuffle(test);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", test));
    }

    static void Shuffle<T>(LinkedList<T> source)
    {
        T[] choices = new T[source.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < choices.Length; i++)
        {
            choices[i] = source.First.Value;
            source.RemoveFirst();
        }

        ShuffleArray(choices);

        foreach (T choice in choices)
        {
            source.AddLast(choice);
        }
    }

    static void ShuffleArray<T>(T[] array)
    {
        // Naturally, in real code you'd want to reuse the same Random object
        // across multiple calls, by making it static readonly
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(i);

            if (i - 1 != j)
            {
                T t = array[i - 1];

                array[i - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```